# Generate gamma and normal distribution in Java? Has anyone done this before?

Tags: java

Has anyone generated Gamma or truncated normal distribution in Java before?  I don't think it is in the built-in package.

I have found this for Gamma: 
blog.javia.org/docs/Gamma.java

I just tried these 3:

1. SSJ from University of Montreal 
   http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~simardr/ssj/indexe.html
2. The JSC library 
   http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/downloads/download.html
3. The eduni package 
   http://www.icsa.inf.ed.ac.uk/research/groups/hase/simjava/distributions/

None works, this is very frustrating.  Am I importing it wrong, or not typing the right command to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CERN COLT](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/api/index.html), and more specifically `cern.jet.random.Normal` and `cern.jet.random.Gamma`

Comment: @rester how should I download it? Could I just obtain their .java source code for gamma distribution?